# How to Change Font or font size on sectionForSectionIndexTitle in iOS objective-c ? or is it true that we can only change color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to Change the color and font of side index titles in tableview . but after hours of googling can't know for sure that either we can only change color or we have option to change font too. Thank you .

Comment: use nsmutablestring with property attribiutedText

Comment: you can chnage the color only , there no property for change the font